# The for loop in this program isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript

It is supposed to print prime n numbers. The for loop will run from 2 to x which will iterate each time. if `i == x` then it means that the number was not divisible and so it should be printed as prime

```js
var n;
var x = 2;
var i;

function prime(n) {
  while (n) {
    for (i = 2; i < x; i++) {
      if (x % i == 0) {
        break;
      }
      if (i == x) {
        document.write(i + " ");
        n--;
      }
      x++;
    }
  }
}

prime(10);
```

Comment: LoL. It goes on an infinite loop in my browser.

Comment: What is your expected output for this. Primes numbers less than `10` or first 10 primes

Comment: This is a very confused algorithm. For example, it compares `i == x` in a loop constrained by `i < x`. `i` will never equal `x` due to that constraint. It also overloads `n` (it's a global variable and a function parameter). It intends to decrement `n` (which it never does), but `n` is what we're trying to determine primeness for. This algorithm makes no sense at all.

Comment: the for loop is never entered, since `i == 2` and `x == 2`, therefore `i < x` is `false`. So the only code that runs is: `while(true){}`

Answer (score 4):

When you try to execute this code, this **will never get into the `for` loop** and goes into an infinite while loop. You have got:

```
i = 2; i < x;
```

The `i` will never be less than `x`. And it doesn't enter the `for` loop and comes out. And `n` will always be `10`, that goes on into an infinite loop.

You need to use the modulus operator to check if a number is divisible by them.

Comment: It should stop when n = 0

Comment: @Eric It's called with `prime(10)`, so `n` will always be `10`.

Comment: I believe the infinite loop is the for loop. Hes incrementing x at the end of every for loop iteration.

Comment: @EricSvitok it *should* stop, yes, but the value of `n` would never be changed. The `if (i == x)` condition would decrement `n` but that is logically impossible to reach because the loop terminates in `i < x`. That condition itself is is the first thing that really happens, so the `for` loop never executes its body.

Comment: @EricSvitok Did you read my answer? For loop doesn't even work here. The condition never satisfies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change your approach a bit and try to find the first X prime number using just for loops.

```js
var n;
var x = 2;
var i;

function prime(n) {
  if (n <= 0) return;

  var i, j, p_no = 0, res = [];
  
  for (i = 2; ; i++) {
    var ifPrime = true;
    for (j = 2; ifPrime && j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
      if (i % j === 0) ifPrime = false;
    }
      
    if (ifPrime) {
      res.push(i);
      console.log(i + ' ');
      p_no++;
        
      if (p_no === n) return res.toString();
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('prime').innerHTML = prime(10);
```

```html
<p id="prime"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening when the code runs is what Praveen describes. I want to address how you got to your algorithm in the first place.

It looks like you're trying to print all primes less than a specific number `n`. You've jumbled different aspects of your algorithm together. Specifically, you've combined a loop that exists to find whether a number is prime with a loop over all numbers less than `n`.

The first thing you can do to help manage this complexity is to use **methods**. If you had a method `isPrime(k)` that returns true or false if a given number is prime, then your function's main loop looks much simpler, and separates the two problems from each other:

```
function prime(n) {
  for (var i = n; i > 1; i--) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      document.write(i + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can focus on defining the isPrime method separately, without getting its parts confused with the main loop:

```
function isPrime(k) {
  for (var i = 2; i < k; i++) {
    if (k % i == 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

**Methods** are a fantastic way of keeping algorithms simpler by isolating their components. They're building blocks one can use to make more complex systems without having to keep track of the whole. It lets you make smaller changes, each encapsulated from other concerns, meaning you have less to keep in your mind while you're making those changes. The less you have to keep in your mind, the easier it is to spot mistakes.

Comment: Terminology correction `isPrime` is a *function*, not a *method*. The difference is not the `function` keyword but rather what is the context of where these are defined. A method belongs to a class, so if you have `primeChecker.isPrime(n)` then that would be invoking a method on the `primeChecker` instance of a class. A function is "free floating" in that it's not attached to a class and thus doesn't have the same kind of context. This does mean that a method of a class in JS can be confusingly defined using the `function` keyword but it should still be called a method.